# In method my List has elements, but when I get out the list is empty

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Back4App which is basically what the old parse.com used to be. I have this piece of code wherein the done method my public List has 5 elements like it's supposed to have. Then once I get out of my method the list is empty.

```
ParseQuery<settings> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(settings.class);
query.whereEqualTo("Username", MainActivity.Display_Name);
query.orderByDescending("createdAt").setLimit(1);

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<settings>() {
public void done(List<settings> settingsList, ParseException exception) {
    for (settings i : settingsList) {
        if (exception == null) {
            creationDate = i.getCreatedAt();
            settingsFrameNumber = i.getFramesPerHive();
            settingsArray.add(0, String.valueOf(settingsFrameNumber));

            settingsHiveNumber = i.getHiveNumber();
            settingsArray.add(0, String.valueOf(settingsHiveNumber));

            settingsHiveBodyNumber = i.getHiveBodies();
            settingsArray.add(0, String.valueOf(settingsHiveBodyNumber));

            settingsSuperNumber = i.getSupers();
            settingsArray.add(0, String.valueOf(settingsSuperNumber));

            settingsYearsOfBeekeeping = i.getYearsofBeekeeping();
            settingsArray.add(0, String.valueOf(settingsYearsOfBeekeeping));

            settingsLocation = i.getLocation();
            settingsArray.add(0, settingsLocation);

            Log.e("Pay Attention", settingsArray.toString());

            }
        }
    }
});

Log.e("Pay Attention", settingsArray.toString());

return settingsArray;
```

The First Log statement returns:`[Littleton, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2]`

The Second Log statement returns: `[]`

I create the list earlier in the class, so it is not just local to the done method.

```
public static List<String> settingsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: How do you know which one's  the first and which one's the second? Since the `findInBackground()` method is async, there may be a race-condition between the two. Why not do `settingsArray = settingsList.clone()` in the `done()` method?

Comment: The log at the bottom probably runs before the log within the done method. That's just how asynchronous code works - you're waiting on a network request, and you should not assume you have data before it finishes despite one code "being above" the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> once I get out of my method the list is empty.

That's the thing, you didn't "get out" of that method - it hasn't been entered yet.

Basically, you shouldn't return from asynchronous methods if you are trying to return the data that you're waiting on.

If you want to correctly return that list, either

1. Pass through `new FindCallback<settings>()` as a parameter to that method, and give it to `findInBackground`
2. Define your own callback interface, which can send data back from within the `done` method.

In both cases, you can make the method `void`.

---

For example, option 1. (I made it static because there doesn't appear to be a need for any instance of the class that contains the method)

```
public static void doStuff(String displayName, FindCallback<settings> callback)

    ParseQuery<settings> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(settings.class);
    query.whereEqualTo("Username", displayName);
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt").setLimit(1);

    query.findInBackground(callback);
}
```

And that's it.

You call it like so, from anywhere, obviously replacing `ApiService` with your actual class name.

```
private List<settings> settings;

private void setupList(List<settings> settings) {
    Log.d("SETTINGS", String.valueOf(settings)); // Shouldn't be empty
    this.settings = settings;

    /* Use the list however you want to... */
    // adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, settings);
    // listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.some_example);

    ApiService.doStuff(MainActivity.Display_Name, new FindCallback<settings>() {
        public void done(List<settings> settingsList, ParseException exception) {
            if (exception == null) {
                ...
                // Update the UI here
                setupList(settingList);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner at this, but what exactly do you mean by "either pass through new FindCallback<settings>() as a parameter to that method, and give it to findInBackground"

Comment: Umm. Which part? Have you ever made a button click listener? Used `setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) { ... } })`? This is practically equivalent to that concept - callbacks provided  through interfaces.

Comment: ok, thank you. When I tested this new code out, I'm still getting an empty array

Comment: How am I supposed to get the correct array out in the if(exception ==null) {

Comment: You don't "get it out", you "pass it along". I've updated again.

Comment: By the way, that `settings` class should really be capitalized if you understand Java variable & class naming conventions.

Comment: Yes, thank you. One more thing is there a way that I can send the value of the array to another fragment?

Comment: Probably, but you should create another post asking for that